# POST query error

Tags: php, mysql

Before I say anything else, I know my  code is a mess and very bad.

ok, for some reason when I submit the form everything works fine but it gives me this error yet I'm not sure why at all.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = 'Nick'' at line 1

This is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['slot1']))
{
    $token = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);
    $tokenn = strip_tags($token);
    $sql55 = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE

    belongsto = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND (id='".$tokenn."')";
    $result55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die(mysql_error());
    $poke55 = mysql_fetch_array($result55);
    $_SESSION['idpoke5'] = $poke55['id'];

    $sql23 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$poke55['pokemon']."'";
    $result23 = mysql_query($sql23) or die(mysql_error());
    $battle_get23 = mysql_fetch_array($result23);

    $result666 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ep=ep+".$battle_get23['ep']." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
        or die(mysql_error());

    $result5done = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_pokemon WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['idpoke5']."'")
        or die(mysql_error());
}
```

It's supposed to pretty much exchange the pokemon for points, it does it just fine. but I get the error for some reason afterwards.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I'm not even seeing the line with the error, but, yes @h2ooooooo's comment should be heeded before you do anything.

Comment: echo all your sql, and check if you get one with an error.

Comment: You need to escape your user input. `$battle_get23['ep']` probably contains invalid data

Comment: I know mysql_ is deprecate I get that comment everytime I post something here, I do this for fun.

Comment: set thi AND id='".$tokenn."'";

Comment: What? @ Engr to short

Comment: You are using two kinds of quotes . see the error.

Comment: I'm not using 2 differnt quotes @ Mark

Comment: Oh well it works just fine if I take out the error output :/ I'll just stop it from outputting the error and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Which row in the php file does the error occur? (I gueess that belongsto should be $belongsto but probably a typo!?)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
   $batleget = $battle_get23['ep'];
   $result666 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ep=ep+CAST($batleget AS UNSIGNED) 
                             WHERE username = '".$username."' ")
```

or this

```
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
   $batleget = $battle_get23['ep'];
   $result666 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ep=ep+ $batleget 
                             WHERE username = '".$username."' ")
```

Comment: @meda , just wonder what you mean here ? what infection you talking about ?